# Passing parameters from a Silverlight application to another XAP files using MEF

Tags: silverlight, mef, parameter-passing

I added a Test.XAP file in my silverlight application and loaded this XAP in my silverlight application using MEF architecture. But Can I send some parameters from my Silverlight application to this test.XAP file ?
If so please send me some working code ... 
or please share some thoughts !!!!